# how to query inside javascript for array on typeahead?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am making a project in school which requires good search engine so I find typeahead good in the eyes but I cannot apply the examples until I find this and I am trying to query my data array inside javascript here as you can see from local but I do not know how to do it, this is my query should be like this:

```
  $con = new mysqli("localhost","root","","casas_jamis") or die(mysqli_error($con)) ;

  $result = $con->query("SELECT firstname,lastname FROM user LIMIT 0,10") or die(mysqli_error($con));
   while ($row = $result->fetch_object()){
     $user_arr[] = $row->firstname;
     $user_arr2[] = $row->lastname;
  }
  $result->close();
  $user_arr[] = $row->firstname;
  echo json_encode($user_arr2);
```

so I want to entry my array for local? how should i do it? please help me, inside the script is the data of alabama alaska arizona and arkansas of local, which I want to replace with my query above:

```
 <script>
// instantiate the bloodhound suggestion engine
var engine = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('d'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  local: [{
    d: "(A)labama"
  }, {
    d: "Alaska"
  }, {
    d: "Arizona"
  }, {
    d: "Arkansas"
   }]
  });

 // initialize the bloodhound suggestion engine
 engine.initialize();

 $('#typeahead').typeahead(null, {
 displayKey: 'd',
 source: engine.ttAdapter()
 });
 </script>
```

I already have this links which finally worked for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>  

 <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.10.2/bloodhound.js"></script> 

 <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.10.2/typeahead.bundle.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.10.2/typeahead.jquery.js"></script>
```